# How to filter Dynamic nested array of JSON objects based on text match with both upper and lower case

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am getting a dynamic nested level array of JSON objects, JSON objects keys properties are dynamic every time. I need to search for matching text records In the dynamic JSON object. The search text can be lowercase or upper cases. I need to filter an array of JSON objects based on search text and even it is not case sensitive and it should work for all types of a nested level dynamic array of JSON objects and filter the records. Great appreciate.

Sample dynamic JSON data added below.

```
[
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"abc1 ",
         "businessEntityDescription":"welcome to the abcd"
      },
      "name":"Paul",
      "applicationName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"view",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Viewers on view"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Removed on: 27-Aug-2020",
         "style":"error"
      },
      "type":"Manager"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"Internal",
         "businessEntityDescription":"Okay"
      },
      "name":"John Smith",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"Master",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Can access read only information of the non-sensitive pages"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 26-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"admin"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"External",
         "businessEntityDescription":"All my Data"
      },
      "name":"ramesh",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"welcome",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"User for My data"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 18-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"HOD"
   }
]
```

Comment: do you want to search for the key or the value?

Comment: @charly1212 Yes in the above Array JSON objects, if I search text chi or CHI or Chi or cHI, it should search and filter the records with the corresponding object. Manually looking above JSON it should return the first two objects because it contains child 1 and child 2 in the last objects we don't have chi maching objects value

Comment: @charly1212 I want to search with the value, Here keys are dynamic

Comment: your array is malformed, there are some brackets too much or missing. can you check please?

Comment: @charly1212 Formated JSON added. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Please post what you have tried.  Edit your question to add clarifications based on comment/questions perhaps.

Comment: JSON is a string, this is not JSON but a JavaScript object...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I will try out the solution and get back. Thank you.

Comment: @charly1212 I have added the Formatted JSON, provided code snippets are not working the updated JSON. Please can you help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not mutate your original array. It will search for the value of deep nested objects in the elements of the array. It even gives back the location of the search result within your array. If nothing is found, empty object will be returned. It searches case insensitive.

```js
const arr = [{
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "abc1 ",
      "businessEntityDescription": "welcome to the abcd"
    },
    "name": "Paul",
    "applicationName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "view",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "Viewers on view"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Removed on: 27-Aug-2020",
      "style": "error"
    },
    "type": "Manager"
  },
  {
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "Internal",
      "businessEntityDescription": "Okay"
    },
    "name": "John Smith",
    "applicationRoleOrGroupName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "Master",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "Can access read only information of the non-sensitive pages"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Active from: 26-Aug-2020",
      "style": "success"
    },
    "type": "admin"
  },
  {
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "External",
      "businessEntityDescription": "All my Data"
    },
    "name": "ramesh",
    "applicationRoleOrGroupName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "welcome",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "User for My data"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Active from: 18-Aug-2020",
      "style": "success"
    },
    "type": "HOD"
  }
]


let findInObject = (obj, str) => {
  let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const re = new RegExp(str, "gi"); //regex to match global case insensitive
  Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
    if (typeof(result[key]) === "string" && result[key].match(re)) { //add here if you don't want to search for style:  && key != "style"  
      result[key] = true;
    } else if (result[key] != undefined && result[key] != null && typeof(result[key]) === "object" && Object.keys(result[key]).length != 0) {
      result[key] = findInObject(result[key], str);
      if (Object.keys(result[key]).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object) {
        delete result[key];
      }
    } else {
      delete result[key];
    }
  });
  return result;
}


let result = arr.map((obj) => findInObject(obj, 'ma')); //Enter you search text here
console.log(result);
```

If you don't like the output format you can just give back the filtered original array:

```js
const arr = [{
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "abc1 ",
      "businessEntityDescription": "welcome to the abcd"
    },
    "name": "Paul",
    "applicationName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "view",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "Viewers on view"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Removed on: 27-Aug-2020",
      "style": "error"
    },
    "type": "Manager"
  },
  {
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "Internal",
      "businessEntityDescription": "Okay"
    },
    "name": "John Smith",
    "applicationRoleOrGroupName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "Master",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "Can access read only information of the non-sensitive pages"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Active from: 26-Aug-2020",
      "style": "success"
    },
    "type": "admin"
  },
  {
    "businessEntityName": {
      "businessEntityName": "External",
      "businessEntityDescription": "All my Data"
    },
    "name": "ramesh",
    "applicationRoleOrGroupName": {
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName": "welcome",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription": "User for My data"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Active from: 18-Aug-2020",
      "style": "success"
    },
    "type": "HOD"
  }
]


let findInObject = (obj, str) => {
  let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const re = new RegExp(str, "gi"); //regex to match global case insensitive
  Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
    if (typeof(result[key]) === "string" && result[key].match(re)) { //add here if you don't want to search for style:  && key != "style"  
      result[key] = true;
    } else if (result[key] != undefined && result[key] != null && typeof(result[key]) === "object" && Object.keys(result[key]).length != 0) {
      result[key] = findInObject(result[key], str);
      if (Object.keys(result[key]).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object) {
        delete result[key];
      }
    } else {
      delete result[key];
    }
  });
  return result;
}


let result = arr.map((obj) => findInObject(obj, 'ma')); //Enter you search text here
let originalFormat = result.map((obj, i) => Object.keys(obj).length ? arr[i] : {}).filter((obj) => Object.keys(obj).length)
console.log(originalFormat);
```

Comment: charly1212 Above code snippet is not working for the above JSON format. Please can you help me? I have updated the JSON data.

Comment: And it should not search from the  "style":"success" property values.

Comment: @RameshLamani ok i have updated my code regarding your changes in the question. you can stop searching for style: success by doing like I wrote in the code comments. please accept the answer to confirm that this is what you was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. it's working Perfectly. Great solution. My requirement is enhanced, after the resulting filter, I need to replace the matching string with bold char in the JSON and needs to display matching text count not filter records count. If search "welcome" keywords it should get replaced with <strong>welcome</strong>, if Search "Ma", it should search "ma" text and replace with <strong>ma</strong> in all matching places. This will be the case insensitive. If I do the above mechanism, I am using react html-react-parser this will take care of the styling. Thanks

Comment: Single sentence can have multiple matching words, needs to highlight those matching char words, and needs to display the total matching count from the entire JSON. Thank you.

Comment: Nice project you have there. I'm glad the solution solved your initial question, if so feel free to accept it as solved. If you have further difficulties you're invited to raise a new specific question showing what you have tried and what doesn't work, to not blow this thread up too much.

Comment: sure, I am closing this thread. solved and a great solution, I have created a new question for the enhancement. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525088/how-to-filter-and-highlight-text-in-the-dynamic-nested-array-of-json-objects-bas Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script below is searching for keys and values containing a search text. Non case sensitive.

Your JSON objects are then in `jsonObjects` (BTW: the JSON is buggy, it misses some brackets).
Pretty sure that the performance can be optimised, but it works.

```js
let searchText = "child";
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
const filteredJsonObjects = jsonObjects.filter(obj => objectContainsString(obj, searchText));

/**
 *  @param {object} obj
 *  @param {string} searchString
 *  @returns {boolean}
 */
function objectContainsString(obj, searchString) {

  if(typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null) {
    return false;
  }

  // Does object has a key named like the searchText?
  // Remove this lines if you don't want to search for the keys too...
  if(Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))) {
    return true;
  }
  
  // else check the values
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = obj[key];

      // If object or array call again...
      if(typeof value === "object" && objectContainsString(value, searchString)) {
        return true;
      }
      if(Array.isArray(value) && value.some(valueInArray => objectContainsString(valueInArray, searchString))) {
        return true;
      }
       
      // Else compare...
      if((typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number") && (value + "").toLowerCase() === searchString) {
        return true;
      }
    }    
  }  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you.