# How to filter and highlight text in the Dynamic nested array of JSON objects based on text match incase sensitive

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am getting a dynamic nested level array of JSON objects, JSON objects keys properties are dynamic every time. I need to highlight the search keyword matching text records In the dynamic JSON object. The search text is incasing sensitives. it should search and work for all types of a nested level dynamic array of JSON objects and needs a count of total number matching records.

I need to replace the matching string with bold char in the JSON and need to display the matching text count. If search "welcome" keywords it should get replaced with ****welcome****, if Search "Ma", it should search "ma" text and replace with ****ma**** in all matching places. This will be the case insensitive. If I do the above mechanism, so I can easily parse JSON tags value, using react html-react-parser, this will take care of the styling.

A single sentence can have multiple matching words, needs to highlight those matching char words, and needs to display the total matching count from the entire JSON.

Sample dynamic JSON data added below.

```
[
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"abc1 ",
         "businessEntityDescription":"welcome to the abcd"
      },
      "name":"Paul",
      "applicationName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"view",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Viewers on view"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Removed on: 27-Aug-2020",
         "style":"error"
      },
      "type":"Manager"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"Internal",
         "businessEntityDescription":"Okay"
      },
      "name":"John Smith",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"Master mass",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Can access read only information of the non-sensitive pages"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 26-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"admin"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"External",
         "businessEntityDescription":"All my Data"
      },
      "name":"ramesh",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"welcome",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"User for My data"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 18-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"HOD"
   }
]
```

If I search "ma" keyword in the above JSON, the expected output should as below

Total matching result coun is 4

```
[
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"abc1 ",
         "businessEntityDescription":"welcome to the abcd"
      },
      "name":"Paul",
      "applicationName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"view",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Viewers on view"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Removed on: 27-Aug-2020",
         "style":"error"
      },
      "type":"<strong>Ma</strong>nager"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"Internal",
         "businessEntityDescription":"Okay"
      },
      "name":"John Smith",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"<strong>Ma</strong>ster <strong>ma</strong>ss",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"Can access read only infor<strong>ma</strong>tion of the non-sensitive pages"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 26-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"admin"
   },
   {
      "businessEntityName":{
         "businessEntityName":"External",
         "businessEntityDescription":"All my Data"
      },
      "name":"ramesh",
      "applicationRoleOrGroupName":{
         "applicationRoleOrGroupName":"welcome",
         "applicationRoleOrGroupDescription":"User for My data"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"Active from: 18-Aug-2020",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "type":"HOD"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy solution could be like:

```
const boldify = (str, search) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(search, "ig");
  return str.replace(reg, (a) => `<strong>${a}</strong>`);
};

const convertedToTextJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
const count = convertedToTextJSON.split(new RegExp(search)).length - 1;
const newJSON = JSON.parse(boldify(convertedToTextJSON, search))
```

Comment: I want to do at the JSON level later will parse, not at the render level. Can you provide the code snippet to modify the JSON based on the search text and replace it? Thanks

Comment: the matching count also required, How can I get it? Thanks

Comment: To count all matches you can use matchAll, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Comment: @Konstantin Modin It should not search in this particular property from the above JSON "style":"success" , except this style key, can search and replace all matching texts. Thanks

Comment: right, so it is buggy solution then. In that case you need to make function where you will manually update each item, applying `boldify` function to each value. This function will return array of `updatedItems` plus it will count matches. Each `item` has the same structure? I can write it.

Comment: @Konstantin Modin The above solutions make changes in both property's keys and values and match all count takes both property's keys and values. I need the solution only it should consider values and replace it and even count for the value match not properties key match. Great appreciate.